# How to display next item on form HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to display next item from array JSON with the `displayItem` function, but after clicking the button, the form reloads the first value (`arrayResponse[0]`). What should I do to display the next item instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstElement;
  var arrayResponse;
  var index =0;    

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // When the file has loaded,
  request.onload = function () {

    // parse the JSON text into an array of post objects.
    arrayResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    firstelement = arrayResponse[0];
    $("#name").val(firstelement.name);
    $("#author").val(firstelement.author);
    $("#content").val(firstelement.content);     
  };

  request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/HTML_JavaScripts_Test/posts.json", true);
  request.send(null);

  $("#nextButton").bind("click", function(){
    displayItem(arrayResponse[index]);
    index++;
  });

  function displayItem(item) {
    $("#name").val(item.name);
    $("#author").val(item.author);
    $("#content").val(item.content);   
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML code and made minimal reproducible snippet?

Comment: Since you're already using jquery, you might want to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

You are only incrementing `index` *after* setting the display.

You set the first element from the `onload`, and then you show that same element from your button click.

This should work :

```
$("#nextButton").bind("click", function(){
    index++;
    displayItem(arrayResponse[index]);
});
```

Comment: @IProgrammer can you provide more details about what data you're getting, and what's the value of index? Basically, `console.log(index, arrayResponse);`. Please add the result in your question

Comment: [
    {
      "name": "Post 1",
      "author": "Joe Schmoe",
    "content": "content"
    },
    {
      "name": "Post 5",
      "author": "Jane Doe",
   "content": "content"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Increment `index` *before* calling `displayItem()`. As it is, you display `arrayResponse[0]` on load, then leave `index` at `0` for the next display.

Instead:

```
$("#nextButton").bind("click", function(){
  index++;

  if (index < arrayResponse.length)
    displayItem(arrayResponse[index]);
});
```

Notice that we're also checking that `index` is valid before calling `displayItem`; no sense trying to display elements past the end of the array.

Comment: Works fine here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoELRp (just skipping the AJAX part; all of the click/next logic is the same)

Comment: yeah work it! but it doesn't work on my browser!!  i am crazing

Answer (score 0):

Right now you load the first item (index 0) and then when you click the next button it loads the same item before you increase the index. Increase the index first and then load the next item

```
$("#nextButton").bind("click", function(){
  index++;
  displayItem(arrayResponse[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will display the next element if you click the button second time.
But if you want to display the next value for the first time you click on button, increase the index first and call the function.

```
 $("#nextButton").bind("click", function(){
    index++;
    displayItem(arrayResponse[index]);    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I understand problem.. Javascripts code is correct! But it doesn't work on my html code...  I tried on another simple html code and work it!

this is my html code :`<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Blog</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head><body><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"/><script  src="main2.js"/><div class="container">  <form id="contact" action="" method="post"><h3>Colorlib Contact Form</h3><h4>Contact us for custom quote</h4><fieldset><input id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" tabindex="1" ></fieldset><fieldset><input id="author" placeholder="Author" type="text" tabindex="2" ></fieldset><fieldset><textarea id="content" placeholder="Content...." tabindex="5" /></fieldset><fieldset>    <button id="nextButton"> Next </button>  </fieldset><p class="copyright">Designed by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank" title="Colorlib">Colorlib</a></p></form></div>    </body></html>`